# Get a most recent updated data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I need to retrieve a series of data for each id from a table. The data or the row value for the column need to be such that it is the second most recent value. For instance, I have
Table- **estimate_record** as following

```
Id        value   last_updated
1         210     10/2018
1         205     11/2018
1         215     12/2018   -- current
```

I need to get the 205 for that particular id =1

I used `Max(value)`, but it's getting `215` which is not right.

Comment: Is `last_updated` a datetime field or a varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by last_updated desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2
```

In earlier versions, one option uses a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.last_updated = (
    select t1.last_updated
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id
    order by t1.last_updated desc
    limit 1 offset 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using MySQL 5.5.

Comment: @Sam: ok. I edited my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: let's say I added two more lines
    2         214     12/2018
    3         300     11/2019
    3         400     12/2019


I need to get the 205 for that particular id =1, but 300 for id = 3.
Also, for that particular id, I also need to find the difference between the current and the last updated one.

Comment: @Sam: it is not a good practice here on SO to change the question after answers were posted. I can only recommend that you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Sure. Although I have this account for a few years now, I rarely use it. I will ask another question.